# How do I put professional affiliations on a CV?

Tags: job, job-search, cv

I am currently a grad student in Psychology. I have heard that many professors like to see a list of 'Professional Affiliations' on a potential employee's CV, because it is an easy way to see whether the two people have common interests.

My question is, are there any guidelines for what I can realistically put there? Should I just list conferences in which I am a current, paying dues member; or can I put any conference in which I've paid dues in the past? Or can I be even less strict that these guidelines?

Comment: @Jeff- You can select "Best Answer" which you feel fits you most.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By 'Professional Affiliations' it is meant that one is a member of certain professional association such as [IEEE](http://www.ieee.org), [ACM](http://www.acm.org), [ICE,](http://www.ice.org.uk) [ASCE](http://www.asce.org) etc.

These professional bodies often arranges conferences which anyone can attend, so registering for the conferences does not mean that one is a member of a organizing body. Conference participation information may be put into your publication list as conference papers and/or given talks section.

So, **You should only list the organisations as professional affiliations of which you are a member.**

Comment: What about research collaborations? Are these to be considered professional affiliations too?

Comment: sorry i wasn't explicit-- at all the conferences i've presented (so far), i've been required to first become a member. but your advice is to only list those which i am a -current- paying member, correct?

Comment: @Nicholas- No. It may be put on as academic affiliation.

Jeff- Yes. You have to be a current paying member. Some conferences require membership, but did you continue your membership till present? If not, then its better not to include in the CV.

Answer (score 3):

Any professional association in which you have been a member.

Conferences are not included in that category, unless they imply membership in some association. For example, registering for the biannual meeting of the [Materials Research Society](http://www.mrs.org) includes membership fees, so if you participated in a meeting, you were a member.

Regarding past membership, I would only include it if you were a member for a significant time.

Comment: I think you're thinking of MRS. AIChE has "biannual" meetings, but the fall meeting is the "Annual" meeting.

Comment: @aeismail yeah, the same probably applies to MRS (though I've never been). Regarding AIChE, they hold meetings twice a year, so even if they call half of them “annual” meetings, they are *biannual* as a matter of fact :)

Answer (score 3):

[Rashed's answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/4959/73) is correct. In addition, though, it is not uncommon to place other notable affiliations towards the end of the resume, if there is space, under whatever title is appropriate. For example, in my resume, I have a "Community Service" section, where I list my membership on various nonprofit boards of directors. If you hold officer position in any other notable groups you could list them similarly.